# Using shorthand assignment in jQuery for element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To double the width of the `img`, i can do this in jQuery:

```
<img src='blah.jpg' id='pic' />

$('#pic').height($(this).height()*2);
```

that works fine, but i really like to use shorthand assignments like:

```
var count = 5;
count *= 2; // to get 10.
```

Since `element.height` returns the height function in jQuery, i can't use shorthand assignments. Is there no way to do shorthand assignments in jQuery for element attributes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify the attributes such as height without using jQuery

```
document.getElementById("pic").height *= 2;
```

Or if you want to select the element with jQuery you can use this snippet.
It selects the element and then accesses it directly using the indexer.

```
$("#pic")[0].height *= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pic').height($('#pic').height() * 2);
```

or

```
  $('#pic')[0].height *= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers question of how to do it in jQuery

```
$('#pic').height(function( i, ht){
   return ht *2;
});
```

See API added function in 1.4.1
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: what does `i` do in the arguments list?

Comment: index of element in collection